# Is it possible to cause Web Workers to Sleep?

Tags: javascript, sleep, web-worker

Since web workers negate the disadvantages of paused execution in JavaScript, as they will not block UI, is there a reliable method to get them to `Sleep`?

Either for a designated time, or until they receive a message?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics/wait

Comment: Considering you are targeting recent browsers, with access to SharedArrayBuffer and Atomics, have a look at these options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701464/is-it-possible-to-pause-resume-a-web-worker-externally/71888014#71888014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Webworkers` are essentially functions that are called via `onMessage`, so getting them to 'sleep' should simply be a matter of sending a specific message to at after a certain period of time.

Unlike threads in languages like Java, `WebWorkers` need not operate in a continuous (and CPU eating) loop in order to retain usefulness; they can be messaged as many times as you please.

In this example, the worker 'sleeps' as it waits for user input.

index.html:

```
<script>
    var worker = new Worker("worker.js");

    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log("Send and recieved " + e.data);
    }

    function tellWorker(element) {
        var data = element.value;
        worker.postMessage(data);
    }

</script>
```

worker.js:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    self.postMessage(e.data);
}
```

Forgive me if I misread your question.

**Edit:**
Another possibility is, assuming the `WebWorker` is running in a `setTimeout` loop, listen for a message that could call `clearTimeout` while a user is doing something.

---

**Update:**

This code will create an object, modify it via the worker, and then modify it again after the parent page adjusts a flag:

index.html:

```
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="startWork()" /><br>
<input type="button" value="passObject" onclick="finishWork()" />

<script>
    var worker = new Worker("worker.js");

    var incompleteObject = {
        val     : 0,
        done    : false
    };


    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log("Exit Status: ");
        console.log(e.data);
    }

    function startWork() {
        worker.postMessage(incompleteObject);
    }
    function finishWork() {
        incompleteObject.done = true;
        worker.postMessage(incompleteObject);
    }

</script>
```

worker.js:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {

    var obj = e.data;

    if(obj.done == false) {
        obj.val = 2;
    } else {
        obj.val = 4;
    }

    self.postMessage(obj);

}
```

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense, I understand workers. However what I want to achieve cannot be done like this. Essentially I want the worker to request an Object from the parent in the middle of a execution block. The worker needs to then 'wait' for the Object to be passed back before it can continue.

Comment: @Jivings could you break the process into two functions? We may need to see some sample code, though I think I know what you want to achieve now. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think breaking the problem into two is what I'm heading toward.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Funnily enough I just wrote out almost the exact same code to test myself, even with the buttons. Thanks for your advice, I'm in the process of re-factoring my code so that it's possible to use a callback as well. If you're interested then I'll post it. Either way, you were very helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Jivings I guess great minds think alike, and ironically, so do we ;) Posting your working code would be beneficial for other viewers with a similar problem.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney you are wrong about how Java threads work. They can suspend, but do it synchronously, and they won't eat CPU. For example, you can call `Object.wait()` and threads suspends on this invocation until some other thread sends a message through `Object.notify()`. While it suspended, it does not consume any resources, except for several kylobytes of memory to store stack and register snapshot. For example, JavaScript callbacks usually consume some memory too to store their closure context.

Answer (score 5):

`setTimeout`and `setInterval` are available to web workers. So if you want to 'wait' your code this may be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't want to wait for a specified interval, I want a method to pause in the middle of execution until it receives a message.

Comment: Have you considered generators?