# Is it possible to pause/resume a web worker externally?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, threadpool, web-worker

I've seen that web workers have a terminate() function, but is there a way to pause and resume web workers from the host thread similar to interrupts?

The critical factor with this question is that using the terminate() call on a web worker will break the state internal to the worker (and any operations taking place may in turn be corrupted in a half-complete state.)  I'm looking for a mechanism by which to switch between hundreds-thousands of tasks held in however many web workers equal the total cores on the machine, without losing state within those tasks or relying on cooperative multithreading styles like fibers.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to pause/resume a web worker externally?

No.  Browser javascript does not have a means of externally pausing web workers without some cooperation from the webWorker itself.

A work-around (with cooperation from the webWorker) would involve the webWorker running a bit of code, then allowing a message to arrive from the outside world that tells it to pause and then the webWorker itself not calling the next unit of work until it receives a message to resume processing.  But, because even webWorkers are event driven, you can't receive a message from the outside world until you finish what you were doing and return back to the event system.

This would probably involve executing a chunk of work, setting a timer for only a few ms from now which allows messages to arrive, then when a message arrives, you store the new pause/resume state and then when the timer fires, you check the state and if its pause, you don't call the next unit of work.  If it's not the pause state, you execute the next unit of work and when it finishes, you again do `setTimeout()` with a really short time (allowing any pending messages to process) and keep going over and over again.

Unfortunately, this technique requires you to chunk your work which negates some of the benefits of webWorkers in the first place (though you still retain the benefit of using more than one CPU to process work).

> I'm looking for a mechanism by which to switch between hundreds-thousands of tasks held in however many web workers equal the total cores on the machine, without losing state within those tasks

You would need to have each currently running webWorker cooperate and allow a message from the outside world to get processed so they could see when the outside world wants them to stop doing more work and then have them cooperatively not call the next unit of work so they wouldn't be doing anything until the next message arrives telling them to start doing their work again.

If you're going to have thousands of these, you probably don't want them all to be individual webWorkers anyway as that's a bit heavy weight of a system.  You probably want a set of webWorkers that are working on a work queue.  You queue up work units to be processed and each webWorker grabs the next unit of work from the queue, processes it, grabs the next unit and so on.  Your main process then just keeps the queue fed with whatever work you want the webWorkers to be doing.  This also requires chunking the work into proper units of work.

Comment: @CoryG - Well, just answering your question - JS doesn't have what you asked for built into webWorkers.  I can see some difficulties with JS trying to implement it too because if the thread is "paused" yet has outstanding asynchronous operations (timers, network requests, etc...), it probably causes errors or problems to leave those unserviced indefinitely.  What would you do with an XMLHttpRequest that was in the middle of reading a bunch of data, for example.

Comment: what every other thread manager does: wait until the thread is reactivated.

Comment: @CoryG - That's perfectly fine in an OS scheduler which is designed to be as fair as possible between all the open threads and give every thread some cycles to keep it going.  It's a different problem if you can pause the thread indefinitely from the outside.  The thread will just stop responding to various things.  Anyways, JS doesn't have what you want.  I'm just answering your question about whether it has that.  It doesn't.

Comment: If a thread is paused indefinitely the expected behavior would be that it stop responding in any context so I don't see how that's especially unique as a javascript problem.  Thank you for the "no," I'm leaving the thread open in the hopes of someone posting an ingenious hack.

Comment: @CoryG - What other languages offer the feature you are interested in as an example?  Do you really want to have hundreds of thousands of "threads" created with most of them paused at any given time?

Comment: @friend00 thus far javascript (specific to web workers, it's possible via node.js because you can get to OS-level interrupts) is the only one I've been unable to do it in.

Comment: This causes me to despair that proper stop but don't kill functionality will never be added to remedy the current deficiency... however in the case of stop (not pause) there is no problem of what to do with outstanding operations - they can still happen, all stop does it terminate current execution as if the current call stack was unwound with returns or even an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are targeting recent browsers, with access to [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) and [Atomics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics). The simplest solution is to pass SAB reference to the worker:

main.js

```js
const sab = new SharedArrayBuffer(4);
const int32 = new Int32Array(sab);

const start = () => {
    const worker = new Worker("worker.js");
    worker.postMessage({kind:"init", sab});
}

const pause = () => {
    Atomics.store(int32, 0, 1);
    Atomics.notify(int32, 0);
}

const resume = () => {
    Atomics.store(int32, 0, 0);
    Atomics.notify(int32, 0);
}
```

...worker loop will wait for the byte to have particular value 1/0.

worker.js

```js
onmessage = event => {
    if(event.data.kind === "init"){
        while(true) {
            Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(event.data.sab), 0, 1);
            ... your bitcoin miner goes here
        }
    }
}
```

In case your worker does not contain synchronous main loop but rather consist of async operations, you can intercept the event loop (block any other line of code to be executed) as follows:

main.js

```js
const sab = new SharedArrayBuffer(4);
const int32 = new Int32Array(sab);

const start = () => {
    const worker = new Worker("worker.js");
}

const pause = () => {
    Atomics.store(int32, 0, 1);
    Atomics.notify(int32, 0);
    worker.postMessage({kind:"pause", sab});
}

const resume = () => {
    Atomics.store(int32, 0, 0);
    Atomics.notify(int32, 0);
}
```

worker.js

```js
... async/await, fetch(), setTimeout()
onmessage = event => {
    if(event.data.kind === "pause")
        Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(event.data.sab), 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: This is cool but only works if you can control the headers for your site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer#security_requirements)

Comment: This still seems to require that you "chunk" your work in some kind of loop.  If that isn't possible, it seems you would start once you received the message but then would run until completely before you checked again.